# How to stop the user from entering on enter tab in rich:tabPanel?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have a rich:tabPanel in my page, what I want is trap the user from entering a tab and say you are 
not allowed to enter in this tab.

How can I achieve that in jquery and javascript. or rich:jQuery maybe?

Another question is how can I disabled this tab using raw jQuery or javascript?
I know this is possible.

I am using richfaces 3 and jsf 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `disabled` attribute to disable it and you can if necessary use the `onclick` attribute to show some alert.

```
<rich:tab disabled="true" onclick="alert('Permission denied')">
```

Comment: what i want is not to use the disabled attribute, and disabled it uing raw javascript or jQuery. Is this possible? thnx